# Debugging gtag events in development environment

Tags: google-analytics, environment, gtag.js

I am setting up gtag.js event handler in my application the system is already in place in the app im working with. However I am looking for a way to confirm it's working before deploying to a staging environment.

Meaning I want to test on my locally running application. I've taken out all blockers in the app for holding off tracking in the development environment and I've tried using https://tagassistant.google.com/ and I've tried using the GA Debug extension as well. However, nothing seems to be logging the events in these debuggers.

I've even tried with existing and fully functioning gtags that were previously implemented. But I get nothing logged in these debuggers.

So my question is, how to test functionality of [google analytics tags](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs) as I develop them before pushing them to a public environment?